# Suitable answers to my A.SE question could be either backed by personal experience OR a reference: Use the reference-request tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have asked [a question on Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75876/alternatives-to-relying-solely-on-student-evaluations-of-teaching-to-more-accura), and I'm looking for answers to my question that are either backed up by personal experience **or** that provide a reference.

Ideally, even a reference-based answer would still include a bit of explanation from the answerer about why the solution mentioned in the reference is, for example, a viable solution to my problem, etc.

> In this case, is it advisable to use the reference-request tag?

I mainly want to make sure that I follow the norms of the site (whatever they may be), and I don't want to turn potential answerers away by using/excluding the reference-request tag.

Related meta question: [How should the reference-request tag be used?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/how-should-the-reference-request-tag-be-used)

Edited to add: the sole answer to this meta question doesn't answer the question I am asking at all (yet, the answer is receiving up votes for some reason). So, I'm hoping to get a useful answer to this question.

Comment: In my experience, if you are explicitly asking for references, people with answer with personal experience anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that, but the most effective approach here would be to [add a bounty to the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). You can only start a bounty two days after the question was posted, so you have some time left.

Adding tags is not a very effective way to look for more answers. Tags are used differently by different users, but I've seen them used mostly for searching, and less for highlighting.

Comment: I think the meta question is whether the tag is appropriate on this kind of question, not whether it is useful for drawing attention.

Comment: @MadJack - Ah, sorry about that. I don't have much to say on that topic.